Microsoft Purview and Azure Synpase Analytics views
I have multiple collections in Microsoft Purview. I have registered an Azure Synapse Analytics source to a parent collection. Depending on the ownership of the datasets I need to scan in views from the same schema to different collections.
When I scan a subset of views from 1 schema to a collection, views that have been added to a different collection using the same schema are removed. The views that are added to these 2 collections from the same schema are different. I need to ensure the views are not removed from either collection.
Any help would be appreciated.
I have set up ignore patterns to ensure only views that should be included when scanned in to collections are included. This ensures only the views I specify are added to the collections.

To prevent views from being removed when scanning a subset of views from one schema to different collections in Microsoft Purview, register the Azure Synapse Analytics source at the root collection level. Then, create subcollections for each ownership group and corresponding scans under each subcollection. This ensures relevant assets appear under each child collection, preventing removal of views from either collection.
